# why codeigniter return false when I have records on my row?

Tags: php, codeigniter

why codeingiter is returning me null in this case null means false because I havent any record on the tabl, when I have records on my table. i'm new using this framework. I just want to display all my user with their passwords and type of user. by the way i'm creating a multi user login.

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('User_model');
    }

    public function index(){
            $data['module'] = "Home";
            $this->load->view('header',$data);
            $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function getAccess(){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        $array = $this->User_model->login($username,$password);
        echo json_encode($array);
    } 

    public function logout(){
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

model

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public $variable;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function login($username,$password){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT iduser,name,last_name,username,password,typeuser_idtypeuser from user INNER JOIN typeuser ON user.typeuser_idtypeuser = typeuser.idtypeuser WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'");
        if($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->result_array();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but don't forget that when you use a string like that for your query, you are responsible for properly escaping your variables. Much better to let CodeIgniter build the query for you.

Answer (score 0):

Modifies the model :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class User_model extends CI_Model {

    public $variable;

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function login($username,$password){
        $query = "SELECT iduser,name,last_name,username,password,typeuser_idtypeuser from user INNER JOIN typeuser ON user.typeuser_idtypeuser = typeuser.idtypeuser WHERE username = ? AND password = ? LIMIT 1";
        $query = $this->db->query($query,array($username,$password));
        if($query->num_rows() != 0){
            return $query->result_array();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

In your Controller verifies the variable $array before the echo:

```
public function getAccess(){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');
        if($array = $this->User_model->login($username,$password)) {
        echo json_encode($array);
        } else { echo 'NO DATA!'; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit Model like this.

```
// it is using Codeigniter Query Builder
public function login($username, $password)
{
    $this->db->select('iduser, name, last_name, username, password, typeuser_idtypeuser');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->join('typeuser', 'typeuser.idtypeuser = user.typeuser_idtypeuser');
    $this->db->where('user.username', $username);
    $this->db->where('user.password', $password);
    $result = $this->db->get();

    if( $result->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $result; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In Controller, you can display like this

```
public function getAccess()
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $array = $this->User_model->login($username, $password);

    // Dispaly Like this 
    foreach ($array->result() as $row) {
        echo $row->iduser; echo " / ";
        echo $row->name; echo " / "; 
        echo $row->last_name; echo " / ";
        echo $row->username; echo " / ";
        echo $row->password; echo " / ";
        echo $row->typeuser_idtypeuser;
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
```

**Remember**, If your input of username or password is not exist in database, you will still receive false.

**To Display All User**
Model should be like this.

```
public function get_all_login()
{
    $this->db->select('iduser, name, last_name, username, password, typeuser_idtypeuser');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->join('typeuser', 'typeuser.idtypeuser = user.typeuser_idtypeuser');
    $result = $this->db->get();

    if( $result->num_rows() > 0 ) {
        return $result; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

In controller, displaying will be the same

```
public function get_all_Access()
{

    $array = $this->User_model->get_all_login();

    // Dispaly Like this 
    foreach ($array->result() as $row) {
        echo $row->iduser; echo " / ";
        echo $row->name; echo " / "; 
        echo $row->last_name; echo " / ";
        echo $row->username; echo " / ";
        echo $row->password; echo " / ";
        echo $row->typeuser_idtypeuser;
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
```

For more info of Codeigniter Query Builder Class, 
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html